# ImportError: liblapack.so.3gf: cannot open shared object file: Input/output error

Tags: python, numpy, ubuntu-12.04

I am importing numpy into python on Ubuntu 12.04 using a PCDuino3. For some odd reason, several of my links in the `/etc/alternatives/` go bad after running my code. When I type `ls -l` in `/etc/alternatives`, I get `?? ??? ??` for all of the file attributes. I cannot remove the link even with super-user. I cannot reinstall numpy or liblapack successfully.

My previous solution is to rebuilt the kernel from scratch and install python-numpy again but that blows. The symbolic link in `/etc/alternatives/` is targeted to `/usr/lib/liblapack/liblapack.so.3gf`. Then my python code runs for several iterations and finally I get the error:

```
ImportError: liblapack.so.3gf: cannot open shared object file: Input/output error
```

Is there a work around to using the libraries in `/etc/alternatives` to use `/usr/lib/liblapack`? Can I use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` when running Python? Is there an equivalent environment variable?

The following is my complete error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/Robotics2015/release/FeederContainerTracker2.0.py", line 12, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from polynomial import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 17, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from linalg import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 23, in <module>
from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite
ImportError: liblapack.so.3gf: cannot open shared object file: Input/output error
```

Comment: If Linux tells you "Input/output error" or attributes show as ??? as root and files cannot be removed, you should be worried that the filesystem is thrashed and may need repair. Your question seems off-topic for stackoverflow, superuser.com could be more appropriate.